# php curl search list of webpage

Tags: php, search, curl, echo

i have the list of http in txt separately by \n
I want by php curl every page and search specify string

the specifc string is :

```
http://www.....com/xyz/...png or .gif


$ch = curl_init("ARRAY of page from txt????");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$text = curl_exec($ch);
$test = strpos($text, "HOW CREATE THE SPECIFIC STRING???");
if ($test==false)
{
    echo $test;
}
else
{
    echo "no exist";
}
```

Comment: Google for `PHP preg_match_all`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('fileName.txt'));

foreach($array as $url){

         $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch); 

        $result[] = $output;  

}
?>
```

finally array $result contain all html for your links that was inside your text file

Answer (score 0):

Do an explode on the url like:
$urls = explode ('\n', urlstring)

Now you can loop through the array of urls.